# SSH client - prompt editable as Windows control

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, putty

Is there a way to configure PuTTY (or some other SSH client) to be aware of what's currently typed into the prompt and make it editable via the mouse (like in an input box / textfield that shows at the bottom of the window)?

This sure would be a nice time saver for certain cases.  I got a taste of this when using an HTML/JavaScript-based shell app.  It had plenty of limitations as compared to a normal shell session, but that aspect of it was nice.

EDIT:

Something like the below (note the control at the bottom of the image).  Or at least some way to click anywhere in the command that's on the prompt to edit it (like imagine being able to click at the beginning of argument2 and start typing another argument, but on a really long command).

[image: /bin/echo argument1 argument2 argument3]

EDIT2: It looks like https://askubuntu.com/questions/359686/in-ubuntu-is-there-any-terminal-that-allows-for-the-position-of-the-cursor-to-b is a decent solution though not quite what I'm hoping for.

Comment: how do you want to edit text by mouse?

Comment: Are you asking if you can position the cursor via the mouse, or is this something else?  http://superuser.com/questions/513014/moving-cursor-in-putty-with-mouse-click

Comment: @Jakuje I've added a mockup of what I'm referring to.

Comment: If you want emacs, I think you can run it even from windows ...